# Is it possible to evaluate $ \int_0^{\pi/2} \cos^2(\cos{x})\cos{x}\,{dx}$ analytically?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I was solving problem of scattering on 2 delta-centers in quantum mechanics and tried to calculate сross section, which leaded me to this integral. I wonder, if it's possible to evaluate it using analytic methods?

$$ \int_0^{\pi/2} \cos^2(\cos{x})\cos{x}\,{dx}$$

Comment: At least Wolfram Alpha says: No result found in terms of standard mathematical functions. But numerically it's $\approx 0.492033$

Comment: @MattiP. WA do know $\int_0^{\pi/2}\cos(2\cos(x))\cos(x)dx = \frac{\pi H_{-1}(2)}{2}$ where $H_\alpha(x)$ is the [StruveH function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Struve_function).

Comment: If I am not mistaken, Wolframp Alpha says it's Struve function, not Hankel

Comment: The problem is, I do not know much about this specific special function, so can someone al least describe how to transform this integral into such representation?

Comment: Mathematica say: $\int_0^{\frac{\pi }{2}} \cos ^2(\cos (x)) \cos (x) \, dx=\frac{1}{4} (2+\pi  \pmb{H}_{-1}(2))$ where: $\pmb{H}_{-1}(2)$ is  Struve function.

Answer (score 1):

$$\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\cos^2(\cos x)\cos x\,dx=\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{1+\cos(2\cos x)}{2}\cos x\,dx\\=\frac12+\frac12\int_0^{\pi/2}\cos(2\cos x)\cos x\,dx\\=\frac12+\frac14\int_0^2\frac{u\cos u}{\sqrt{4-u^2}}du\\
=\frac12+\frac14\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n)!}\int_0^2\frac{u^{2n+2}}{\sqrt{4-u^2}}$$
Now WolframAlpha, that I could connect via internet, can calculate the rest:
$$\frac12+\sqrt{\pi}\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n4^{n-1}n!}{(2n)!\Gamma(n+\tfrac32)}$$

Comment: What do you get if you re-write $n!/(2n)!$ via [(5.5.5)](https://dlmf.nist.gov/5.5.E5) and then use [(11.2.1)](https://dlmf.nist.gov/11.2.E1)?

Comment: @Gary $1/2+\pi H_{-1}(2)/2$?